# Cannot import my self-defined msg in ROS using Python

Tags: ros, python, ros-kinetic, msg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I'm quite new in programming using Python, but I need to use it in order to call some libraries in ROS I've downloaded from Github. The thing is that I need to call a msg I've created (it works in ROS using C++), but when I try to load it in a Python script using `from my_pkg.msg import my_msg` it just exit because of the following error:

`ImportError: No module named msg`

I've followed the instruction you can find in this tutorial [1](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingMsgAndSrv#Creating_a_msg) and I've read a lot of topics, but I still cannot solve it. The thing is that for what I can understand from other topics and user answer, Python makes itself a mess and cannot find the module. There's something I might be forgeting. Any idea?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/335385/cannot-import-my-self-defined-msg-in-ros-using-python/) by [drodgu](https://answers.ros.org/users/43205/drodgu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 59 on 2019-10-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I guess your custom messages are in the package named `my_pkg`. Add that package in your `package.xml` so the messages are built before this package is to be used:

```
<depend>my_pkg</depend>
```

If you have already done so, you can also check this [question](https://answers.ros.org/question/105711/rospy-custom-message-importerror-no-module-named-msg/).

---

Originally posted by [pavel92](https://answers.ros.org/users/32610/pavel92/) with karma: 1655 on 2019-10-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [drodgu](https://answers.ros.org/users/43205/drodgu/) on 2019-10-15**:
I'm sorry I answer you so late. I've tried but failed. The compiler says that you cannot load that package on my_pkg or something like that. Finally I've decided to create a new package with al my messages and use that package messages instead.

Thank you very much for your quick answer!